# TFS Build servers and critical Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, build

When you build on a TFS build server, failed unit tests cause the build to show an orange alert state but they still "succeed".  Is there any way to tag a unit test as critical such that if it fails, the whole build will fail?

I've Googled for it and didn't find anything, and I don't see any attribute in the framework, so I'm guessing the answer is no. But maybe I'm just looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Are you using MsTest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to do this, but you need to create multiple test runs and then filter your tests. On your tests, set a TestCategory attribute:

```
[TestCategory("Critical")]
[TestMethod]
public void MyCriticalTest {}
```

For NUnit you should be able to use `[Category("Critical")]`. There are multiple attributes of a [test you can filter on, including the name](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vikramagrawal/archive/2012/07/23/running-selective-unit-tests-in-vs-2012-rc-using-testcasefilter.aspx).

- Name = `TestMethodDisplayNameName`
- FullyQualifiedName = `FullyQualifiedTestMethodName`
- Priority = `PriorityAttributeValue`
- TestCategory = `TestCategoryAttributeValue`
- ClassName = `ClassName`

And these operators:

- = (equals)
- != (not equals)
- ~ (contains or substring only for string values)
- & (and)
- | (or)
- ( ) (paranthesis for grouping)

XUnit .NET [currently does not support TestCaseFilters](https://twitter.com/bradwilson/status/557249474171371520).

Then in your build definition you can create two test runs, one that runs Critical tests, one that runs everything else. You can use the [Filter option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms253138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the Test Run.

Open the Test Runs window using this hard to find button:
[image]

Create 2 test runs:
[image]

On your first run set the options as follows:
[image]

On your second run set the options as follows:
[image]

This way Team Build will run any test with the "*Ciritical*" category in the first run and will fail. If the first run succeeds it will kick off the non-critical tests and will Partially Succeed, even when a test fails.

### Update

The [same process explained for Azure DevOps Pipelines](https://jessehouwing.net/staged-execution-of-tests-in-azure-devops-pipelines/).

Comment: This is like exactly what I was looking for.  That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Using the TFS2013 Default Template:

Under the "Process" tab, go to section 2, "Basic".

Expand the Automated Tests section.

For "Test Source", click the ellipsis ("...").

This will open a new window that has a "Fail build when tests fail" check box.